# Lock Mac mini but keep secondary display running

Tags: display, mac-mini, appletv

I am configuring a dashboard on a TV display to show latest sales stats, etc. and am running this off our existing build 'server', a Mac mini. The Mac mini is connected to a standard monitor and a TV using AppleTV. What I'm after is a way to keep the Mac mini running in the background, with the standard monitor, USB keyboard and mouse disabled but to keep the main TV on showing a chrome browser with our dashboard app in it.

I'm pretty sure I'm asking for something impossible but I wondered if anyone had any suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you won't be able to lock your Mac Mini as it will trigger the login screen. Also, if you disable the USB Keyboard and Mouse, how would you take back control on your Mac Mini ? My best bet is a locked case where you put your Mac Mini, keyboard and mouse inside and just lock all inside the case.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [status board](https://panic.com/statusboard/) and an old iOS device to run the status board, but perhaps that's not the suggestion you are hoping to get. OS X doesn't allow one screen to opt out of locking - the current user is all or none in terms of keyboard input.

You could also develop custom kiosk software. But I've only seen that lock all the screens - not one.